# Procedure? return false for variable

Tags: scheme, racket

So this line of code:

```
(procedure? (eval x))
```

evaluates to true when x is a procedure, but doesn't work if x is a variable as I get the following error:

```
cannot reference undefined identifier
```

How can I rewrite that snippet of code so that it evaluates to false when x is a variable and true when x is true?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why do you use `eval`? `x` will be evaluated automatically before being passed as an argument to `procedure?` so you can just use `(procedure? x)`:

```
> (define x (lambda (e) (+ e 1)))
> (procedure? x)
#t
> (define y '(1 2 3))
> (procedure? y)
#f
> (define z 3)
> (procedure? z)
#f
```